# Camera preview in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating one app which uses camera. camera is perfectly working in both landscape and portrait. But the Result Image is perfectly set with in the frame at the landscape mode. but in portrait , the result image set in the frame at 90 degree orientaion.how to fix this problem?

```
   public void createImageInImageCenter() {



    Bitmap backgroundBitmap = DgCamActivity.photo;



    backgroundBitmap = backgroundBitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            backgroundBitmap, 900, 700, true);


    Bitmap bitmapToDrawInTheCenter = null;
    File f = new File(FrameGridView.selected_img);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    try {
        bitmapToDrawInTheCenter = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bitmapToDrawInTheCenter = bitmapToDrawInTheCenter.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, 900, 700, true);

    resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),
            backgroundBitmap.getHeight(), backgroundBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, new Matrix(), null);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, 0, 0, new Paint());

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.final_img);
    image.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code it's helpful to you for handle image rotation.

```
public class CaptureImage extends Activity {

private static final int PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE = 2;

ImageView img;
Button btn;
double d = 1.2;

private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

public static String userPicPath;
File file;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_image);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_capture_image_img);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setText(String.valueOf(d));

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/MyImage", "img_"
                    + dateFormatter.format(new Date()).toString() + ".png");
            userPicPath = file.getPath();
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_CAMERA_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Log.d("CaptureImage", mImageCaptureUri.toString());

        Bitmap bitmapProfile = getBitmap(userPicPath, this);

        img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap(file, bitmapProfile));

    }
}

public static Bitmap rotatedBitmap(File imageFile, Bitmap source) {

    try {
        int rotate = 0;
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        }

        Log.v("Capture Image", "Exif orientation: " + orientation + ":"
                + String.valueOf(rotate));

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static Bitmap getBitmap(String path, Context context) {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    InputStream in = null;
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    try {
        // final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 2048;
        final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1024;
        in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
        in.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(
                    2,
                    (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                            / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                            / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, stream);
        in.close();

        return b;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("CaptureImage", "file " + path + " not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CaptureImage", "file " + path + " not found");
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

and layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Capture Image" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/activity_capture_image_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: this code is resolved you issue then please upvote and correct as an answer

Comment: sry @Shaileshi try this code it not working. bitmapToDrawInTheCenter = bitmapToDrawInTheCenter.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, 900, 700, true);

    resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),
            backgroundBitmap.getHeight(), backgroundBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, new Matrix(), null);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, 0, 0, new Paint());

Comment: i think my problem is canvas.drawBitmap .. please read my code and give a solution

Comment: @Gopal What is you exact problem image rotation or image createImageInImageCenter? because above code for handle image rotation.

Comment: i need to capture the image and fix it in center of the frame. it perfectly worked in landscape but in portrait image rotated. the captured image take rotation in portrait.. pls help me

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. Before Android API 13, the retrived image from the camera was the same that the preview one, but after API 13 they have inverted the Y axis from the preview. It is the "real" view from the point of the camera. Apply this function to your bitmap :

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source) {
  orientation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

  if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
    float[] mirrorY = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
    matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);
    matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);
  }

  switch (orientation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
      if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
        matrix.postRotate(90);
      } else {
        matrix.postRotate(270);
      }
     break;

     case Surface.ROTATION_90:
       matrix.postRotate(0);
     break;

     case Surface.ROTATION_180:
       if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
         matrix.postRotate(270);
       } else {
         matrix.postRotate(90);
       }
       break;

       case Surface.ROTATION_270:
         matrix.postRotate(180);
       break;
  }

  return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

This is for processing the image or saving it to the sdcard for example. But if the rotation problem occurs in your preview, use this rotation in your "surfaceChanged" method :

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
orientation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

switch (orientation) {
  case Surface.ROTATION_0:
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
  break;

  case Surface.ROTATION_90:
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
  break;

  case Surface.ROTATION_180:
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
  break;

  case Surface.ROTATION_270:
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
  break;
}
```

Tested and working on Android 4.x (AOSP, Cyanogen, and FirePhone).

Comment: i am also using this method to camera orientation. the problem is camera.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);  it working perfectly in landscape.in portrait image fit in 90 degree rotation.

Comment: thanks.....your code working correctly .but the frame also rotated.. i want rotate only the image taken by camera..